# How to locate image location in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

How can I locate properly locate image under laravel 5.2 folder? The image is located under `logos` folder. The structure of my folder is `application\resources\views\templates\partials\logos`. When I run this it give's me a crap picture.

```
<ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @if (Auth::check())
       <li><a href = "#"><img src = "img/home.png"></a></li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel locates all client-side files inside `public` folder so list your files there, just copy it from `resources/views` into `public`, then you shall have access to such functions (or keep your files where they are, but mind the location these functions take from or use).

**Dirty fast solution**
Since blade will render and cache your views you might use the public folder URL as your root and you are totally fine to list your image from such location (after copying files in your case to public folder).

```html
    <img src="templates/partials/logos/01.png" alt="">
```

**Neat way**

```html
<img src="{{asset('img/photo.jpg')}}" alt="">

<img src="{{secure_asset('img/photo.jpg')}}" alt="">
```

Others based on path: **Please mind these directories permissions, AGAIN don't use it for public access, please** (Except `public_path()` and yes `storage_path()` is fine too)

```php
app_path()
base_path()
public_path()
storage_path()
```